# how to display and hide the container view on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibaction

I have a view controller which consists of a container view which is half of the screen size over an image view, which is initially hided.
the container is embedded with the tableView.
i have a button which on click will display the container view and on the second click it should hide

i have tried like this

```
- (IBAction)OnClickingIndicator:(id)sender {
    [self.childViewControllers[0] view].hidden = NO;
}
```

it is getting displayed but to hide on second click how to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will work fine for me.Please try it.

```
- (IBAction)OnClickingIndicator:(id)sender {
    [self.childViewControllers[0] view].hidden = ![self.childViewControllers[0] view].hidden
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an IBOutlet of that Container View.

```
@IBOutlet var containerView:UIView!
```

On button action show/hide it:

```
- (IBAction)OnClickingIndicator:(id)sender {
    containerView.hidden = !containerView.hidden
}
```

Comment: Tag contains Objective-c ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)makeVisible:(id)sender {

    [self.childViewControllers[0] view].hidden = NO;

}
```

if you want to add the child view controller in response to an event .Try this

```
UIViewController *child = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"yourIdentifier"];
[self addChildViewController:child];
[child didMoveToParentViewController:self];
child.view.frame = CGRectMake(//your frame);
[self.view addSubview:child.view];
```